# How can I check if two JTextfields are empty and display a JOptionpane if they are?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Below is the method that I need to add the code to. It should check to see if the Jtextfields are empty and show a JOptionpane if they are. if not, it should call the calculateSubtotal method

```
private void calculateBillJButtonActionPerformed(    
  ActionEvent event )
```

{
      double total = calculateSubtotal();

```
  // display subtotal, tax and total   
  displayTotal( total );
```

} // end method calculateBillJButtonActionPerformed

Comment: The JTextFields are called "waiterNameJTextField" & "tableNumberJTextField"

Comment: getText().isEmpty()?

Comment: Thanks madProgrammer but I am a newbie and do not know where to put the JTextField names or the code for the JOptionPane. Can you elaborate please? Thanks